# Need help todesign ER Diagram

Tags: erd

How can i design this ER Diagram

The Ministry of Transportation (MOT) supplies department keeps track of all the items (furniture and equipment such as a chair or printer) in the Ministry offices. There are several MOT buildings and each one is given a different name to identify it. Each item is assigned a unique ID when it is purchased. This ID is used to keep track of the item, which is assigned to a room within a building. Each room within a building is assigned to a department, and each department has a single employee as its manager.

Answer (score 0):

i am trying several time but can't understand what to do.If anyone can simplified then it can be much easier for me.